# how to update a login name in header component from logincomponent in angularjs 4.0

Tags: node.js, angular

Hi I need to update login name in a header after a user logs in.
this is my code:

app.componet.html

```
    <app-header></app-header>    
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MyservicesService } from './myservices.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
    constructor(private myservices: MyservicesService) {         

    }

}
```

Header.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a routerLink="home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="shop">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutus">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contactus">Contact</a></li>
                <li *ngIf="displayuser" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle displaycurrentuser" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{currentusername}}
                     <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a (click)="logOut()">Log out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li *ngIf="!displayuser"><a href="#" routerLink="loginorregister"><button style="margin-top: -10px;" class="btn btn-primary"> Login / Register</button></a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="cartlist"><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{noofitemsincart}} </span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication.service';
import { MyservicesService } from '../myservices.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
displayuser:boolean = false; 
 currentusername;
 noofitemsincart;
 user:any;
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,private myservices: MyservicesService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.user = this.authenticationService.getCurrentUserData();

         if(this.user!=null){
           //this.user=JSON.parse(this.user);
          if(this.user.UserNameorEmail!=null){
           this.displayuser=true;
            console.log("displayuser "+this.displayuser);
             this.currentusername=this.user.UserNameorEmail;
           }
        } 
  }
  logOut() {
        this.user= this.authenticationService.logout(); 
        this.displayuser=false;   
  }

}
```

Loginorregistercomponent.html

```
<section class="news_area newsblock">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="section-title">
                <h2>my <span>account</span></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--endrow-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 spaceblock">
                <div class="login">
                    <h3 class="titlel">Login</h3>
                </div>
                <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="loginform.form.valid && login()" #loginform="ngForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="loginpart">
                        <div class="form-group froma" [ngClass]="{'has-error': loginform.submitted && !username.valid}">
                            <label for="email">Username or email address <span class="required"> *</span></label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="" name="username" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username"
                                #username="ngModel" required>
                            <div *ngIf="loginform.submitted && !username.valid" class="help-block">Username is required</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': loginform.submitted && !password.valid }">
                            <label for="pwd">Password<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel"
                                required>
                            <div *ngIf="loginform.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                        <button [disabled]="lloading" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        <img *ngIf="lloading" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAPIAAP///wAAAMLCwkJCQgAAAGJiYoKCgpKSkiH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh/hpDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggYWpheGxvYWQuaW5mbwAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMwi63P4wyklrE2MIOggZnAdOmGYJRbExwroUmcG2LmDEwnHQLVsYOd2mBzkYDAdKa+dIAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADNAi63P5OjCEgG4QMu7DmikRxQlFUYDEZIGBMRVsaqHwctXXf7WEYB4Ag1xjihkMZsiUkKhIAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzYIujIjK8pByJDMlFYvBoVjHA70GU7xSUJhmKtwHPAKzLO9HMaoKwJZ7Rf8AYPDDzKpZBqfvwQAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzMIumIlK8oyhpHsnFZfhYumCYUhDAQxRIdhHBGqRoKw0R8DYlJd8z0fMDgsGo/IpHI5TAAAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAAAzIIunInK0rnZBTwGPNMgQwmdsNgXGJUlIWEuR5oWUIpz8pAEAMe6TwfwyYsGo/IpFKSAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMwi6IMKQORfjdOe82p4wGccc4CEuQradylesojEMBgsUc2G7sDX3lQGBMLAJibufbSlKAAAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAADMgi63P7wCRHZnFVdmgHu2nFwlWCI3WGc3TSWhUFGxTAUkGCbtgENBMJAEJsxgMLWzpEAACH5BAkKAAAALAAAAAAQABAAAAMyCLrc/jDKSatlQtScKdceCAjDII7HcQ4EMTCpyrCuUBjCYRgHVtqlAiB1YhiCnlsRkAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAA=="
                        />

                        <div class="lostpass"><a href="#">Lost your password?</a></div>
                        <div *ngIf="lerror" class="danger">{{lerror}}</div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 spaceblock">
                <div class="login">
                    <h3 class="titlel">Register</h3>
                </div>
                <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="registerform.form.valid && register()" #registerform="ngForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="loginpart">
                        <div class="form-group froma" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': registerform.submitted && !newusername.valid }">
                            <label for="email">Email address <span class="required"> *</span></label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="" name="newusername" [(ngModel)]="registermodel.newusername"
                                #newusername="ngModel" required>
                            <div *ngIf="registerform.submitted && !newusername.valid" class="help-block">Username is required</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': registerform.submitted && !newpassword.valid }">
                            <label for="pwd">Password<span class="required"> *</span></label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="" name="newpassword" [(ngModel)]="registermodel.newpassword"
                                #newpassword="ngModel" required>
                            <div *ngIf="registerform.submitted && !newpassword.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" [disabled]="rloading" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                        <img *ngIf="rloading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"
                        />
                        <div *ngIf="rerror" class="danger">{{rerror}}</div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--endimgSection-->
    </div>
</section>
```

Loginorregistercomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loginorregister',
  templateUrl: './loginorregister.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loginorregister.component.css']
})
export class LoginorregisterComponent implements OnInit {

 model: any = {};
 registermodel: any = {};
    lloading = false;
    rloading = false;
    returnUrl: string;
    lerror;
    rerror;
  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.authenticationService.logout();

        // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
       this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
  }
  login() {
        this.lloading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                console.log(data);
                if(!data.hasOwnProperty('Code')){
                  this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                }else{

                  this.lerror=data.Message;
                  console.log(this.lerror);
                    this.lloading = false;
                }
                
                },
                error => {
                    //this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.lerror=error;
                    console.log(error);
                    this.lloading = false;
                });    

    
     }
  register() {
        this.rloading = true;
        this.authenticationService.create(this.registermodel.newusername, this.registermodel.newpassword)
            .subscribe(
                data => {

                    data=JSON.parse(data);
              if(!data.hasOwnProperty("Code")){
                  this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                  console.log("in data "+data);
                }
                else{
                  console.log("out data "+data.Message);
                    this.rerror=data.Message;
                    this.rloading = false;
                }
                },
                error => {
                   // this.alertService.error(error);
                   this.rerror=error;
                    this.rloading = false;
                });    
  }


}
```

authenticationService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  user:any;
   headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
 options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

  constructor(private http: Http) { }


 login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post('http://www.myweb.com/User/Login', JSON.stringify({UserNameorEmail: username,Password: password}),this.options)
            .map((response: Response) => {

                let user = response.json();
                console.log("in service "+user);
                if (user) {

                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    console.log("user.token "+user);
                }

                return user;
            });

    }


    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }

    create(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post('http://www.myweb.com/User/Add', JSON.stringify({UserNameorEmail: username, Password: password }),this.options)
            .map((response: Response) => {

                let user = response.json();
                if (user) {

                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }

                return user;
            });

    }

    getCurrentUserData(){
        this.user= localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
         this.user=JSON.parse(this.user);  
         if(this.user!=null){
          if(this.user.UserNameorEmail!=null){
            return this.user;
           }else{
                return this.user=null;
           }
        }else{
                return this.user=null;
           }
    }


}
```

Comment: sum up what you tried and what's not working and add if there's any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically have a state.service.ts in my projects in which I store application state (current user etc.)

In this, I create the following:

```
  // BehaviorSubject to store UserName
  private currentUserNameStore = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  // Make UserName store Observable
  public currentUserName$ = this.currentUserNameStore.asObservable();

  // Setter to update UserName
  setCurrentUserName(userName: string) {
    this.currentUserNameStore.next(userName);
  }
```

Then in the header component where you need to display the current User, you subscribe to the Observable from your state service:

```
stateSvc.currentUserName$
  .subscribe(
  userName => {
    userName = userName;
  });
```

And you can display this in the header like this:

```
{{userName}}
```

Then in your login component, once you've got a logged in user, you set the value using the Setter in the service:

```
this.stateSvc.setCurrentUserName(this.userName);
```

As the Title on the header component is subscribed, it will pickup the changes and update the display on the component.

Comment: yes,your code working but one problem if page reload it shows empty..
what i do when reload

Comment: To survive page reloads you have to save your state information in something persistent, which is usually via LocalStorage. Then when your state service initializes, it checks to see if there's data in LocalStorage and restores it, and updates LocalStorage with any new information whenever you update the store via a Setter.

Comment: If this answer solved your initial question, please mark it as the correct answer and then ask a new question regarding how to implement local storage in a state service, otherwise unrelated but useful answers to that problem will get buried in comments and be difficult for other people to find in future.

Comment: yes,i got it,thanks for your answer now i solved my problem.
thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You have to check authenticity of user before loading `<app-header> </app-header>`

i.e.

`<div *ngIf="authorised">
 <app-header></app-header>

</div>`

where authorised is a member of app.component.ts.
i.e. You have to make sure if displayuser or currentusername is available before rendering `<app-header></app-header>`.

Please mark if you find it helpful.